# Extract or play youtube audio with Vbscript

Tags: audio, vbscript, youtube

I am trying to get a vbs script to ask for a url of a youtube video and play the audio. I have this so far

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim Msg,Question,PathSound,URL
    URL = InputBox("What url would you like to play from?")
    PathSound = "URL"
    Question = MsgBox(Msg,VbQuestion+VbYesNo,Msg)
    If Question = VbYes Then
    Call Play(PathSound)
    Else
    Wscript.Quit()
    End If
    '**********************************************************
    Sub Play(SoundFile)
    Dim Sound
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    Sound.URL = SoundFile
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.Controls.play
    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
    wscript.sleep 100
    loop
    wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
    End Sub
    '**********************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Msg,Question,URL,Title
Title = "Extract or play youtube audio with Vbscript by Hackoo 2016"
Msg = "Did you want to continue with this script to play music ? or stop music and quit this script ?"
Question = MsgBox(Msg,VbQuestion+VbYesNo,Title)
If Question = VbYes Then
    URL = InputBox("What url would you like to play from ?" , "Play Sound from internet",_
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Aa9GwWaRv0")
'http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx
    If URL = "" Then Wscript.Quit()
    If Instr(URL,"youtube") > 0 Then
        Call Play_Youtube(URL)
    Else    
        Call Play(URL)
    End If  
Else
    Call Kill("iexplore.exe")
    Call Kill("Wscript.exe")
    Wscript.Quit()
End If  
'**********************************************************
Sub Play(SoundFile)
    Dim Sound
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    Sound.URL = SoundFile
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.Controls.play
    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
        wscript.sleep 100
    loop
    wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
End Sub
'**********************************************************
Sub Play_Youtube(URL)
    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate(URL)
    ie.Visible=false
    DO WHILE ie.busy 
    LOOP
End Sub 
'**********************************************************
Sub Kill(Process)
    Dim Command,Ws,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "& Process &""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
End Sub
'***********************************************************
```

Comment: if i put in a new address it would play different videos.

Comment: @AlienVilliger give me this new adress to test with you

Comment: I wont stop playing the audio EVER.